# get post author id outside loop

Tags: customization, author, id

I need to place in post edit dashboard metabox with post author e-mail (or other user meta fields). So it can be edited when admin reviews this post.

```
$meta_id = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $user_id );

$meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'my-meta-box',
    'title' => 'DANE FIRMY',
    'page' => 'post',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'E-mail box',
            'id' => 'mail',
            'type' => 'text',
            'std' => $meta_id
        )
    )
);
```

This code works when $user_id is an integer (when I manually put there for example 4) but i want to dynamically get current author id ( `$user_id` ).

`get_the_author_meta('user_mail')` should work without specifying `$user_id` (codex says that :)) but code is in `functions.php` and outside the loop so it doesn't work. I'm starting with Wordpress and PHP so I don't know what to do next.

Also tried this:

```
global $post;
$user_id=$post->post_author;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'myprefix_edit_form_after_title' );
function myprefix_edit_form_after_title() {
    global $post;
    $author_id=$post->post_author;
    $authord = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $author_id);
    echo $authord;
}
```

With this function I was able to display post author e-mail in post edit screen. Still don't know how to make  it work with custom meta field but I think Im closer now.

Comment: It's also your own question.  You can edit it to clarify.

Answer (score 39):

The easiest way would be using [`get_post_field()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field):

```
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
```

For more details on this issue: have a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558834/1743124).

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following:

```
/**
 * Gets the author of the specified post. Can also be used inside the loop
 * to get the ID of the author of the current post, by not passing a post ID.
 * Outside the loop you must pass a post ID.
 *
 * @param int $post_id ID of post
 * @return int ID of post author
*/
function wpse119881_get_author( $post_id = 0 ){
     $post = get_post( $post_id );
     return $post->post_author;
}
```

Comment: Hmm it doesnt work for me - i think function must be hooked to one of filters but dont know which.

Comment: Works for me... are you sure you're passing it a (valid) post ID?

Comment: But i want to display this meta field in edit screen for every post (not just for one) and post author can be different so $post_id must be loaded dynamically according to edit screen.

Comment: Set `$post_id` dynamically. If using inside a metabox, your metabox callback will be passed the `$post` object. So you can use `$post->ID` (You can probably just use `$post->post_author` for that meta.